# How to hide DIV in paging

Tags: database-design, paging

I have an onclick button that removes all DIV a result. But it only removes the DIV's that are in the paging 1. The other results are in paging 2.3 ... etc are not removed. How to solve it?

```
function removeDiv (){
$('#divPlay').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
}

<a onclick="removeDiv()">Remove</a>
```

Pagination 1: Ok
[image: PAGINATION 1]

Pagination 2: Error
[image: PAGINATION 2]

Comment: Nothing to do with databases - voting to close here and migrate to StackOverflow.

Comment: Could you please give more information, and show us the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

attach event to buttons action pagination. The moment of pagination the content is rendered for display and leftover is destroyed.

```
$('contentActions').delegate('a','click',removeDiv)
```